# Game Crashing when Random Spawn happens on Snake

Tags: html

I think when an apple spawns on the snake in my snake game, the game keeps keeps crashing (loading indefinitely). I'm having troubles with my code making the apple spawn on a random location NOT on the snake.

```
  function spawnApple() {
  // Generate a random position for the apple
  apple.x = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
  apple.y = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
```

```
      // snake occupies same space as a body part. reset game
      if (cell.x === snake.cells[i].x && cell.y === snake.cells[i].y) {
        snake.x = 160;
        snake.y = 160;
        snake.cells = [];
        snake.maxCells = 4;
        snake.dx = grid;
        snake.dy = 0;

        apple.x = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
        apple.y = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
        while (snake.cells.some(c => c.x === apple.x && c.y === apple.y)); {
    // If it does, generate a new random position for the apple
    apple.x = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
    apple.y = getRandomInt(0, 25) * grid;
  }
```

Comment: Typo?  The `while` loop has a semi-colon, making it an empty loop body.

Comment: Oh my goodness. I'm an idiot. I've been staring at this for 3 days wondering what's wrong. That's exactly what it was. Thank you! Solved.

Comment: I have no idea if the Javascript interpreter actually raises an exception or otherwise terminates your program on an infinite loop, but I would be surprised if it does because that's essentially the Halting Problem. You should be mindful in general of the term _"crash"_. A crash is when something unexpected causes your program to be forcefully terminated without user intervention. What you have here is not a crash. It's more like a _freeze_ or _lock-up_, which  is when your program becomes unresponsive, with or without excessive CPU usage.

Comment: Update: This actually is still freezing. However, it's not in my terminal. Only on the actual website (which is hosted through Google Sites) Could it be a hosting issue?